# Is there a way to convert a shader code to shader graph?

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders

I would like to ask if there is a way to convert a Coded shader into the new Shader graph, beacause i want to edit my shaders in more efficient way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By shader graph, do you mean something like Unity's Shader Forge? What have you tried so far? If you just want to create shaders using a GUI instead of code, have you searched for any program/addon that does that?

Comment: Your question as it stands is not enough information for us to assess your problem. You need to put more info into what you have tried and what you want or your question will likely be closed as unclear